# Why sometimes exception can't be captured in Spec2?

Tags: scala, exception, testing, spec2

The scala test code:

```
import play.api.test._
import scala._
import org.specs2.execute.Result

object ThrowTest extends PlaySpecification {

  "throwA" should {
    "catch the exception test1" in {
      world must throwA[Exception]
    }
    "catch the exception test2" in {
      hello {
        world =>
          world must throwA[Exception]
      }
    }
  }

  def hello(action: (String) => Result) = {
    action(world)
  }

  def world: String = {
    throw new Exception("world-exception")
  }

}
```

Why `test1` is working as I expected, but `test2` is not, which throws the exception to outer and never catch it:

```
[info] ! catch the exception test2
[error]     Exception: world-exception (ThrowTest.scala:26)
[error] database.ThrowTest$.world(ThrowTest.scala:26)
[error] database.ThrowTest$.hello(ThrowTest.scala:22)
[error] database.ThrowTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(ThrowTest.scala:14)
[error] database.ThrowTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(ThrowTest.scala:14)
[info] Total for specification ThrowTest
```

Answer (score 2):

Because for test 2 your exception is thrown from `hello` *before* calling `action`. `action` is a `String => Result` and you call it with `world` which - when evaluated - throws an exception, therefor, all this code:

```
world =>world must throwA[Exception]
```

is never executed.

Comment: just to make it a little bit explicit, what you (@Freewind) have in your code in hello function is: `val result = world; action(result)`